# Where to write exceptions

Tags: asp.net, exception

I am making a web application, this is my first application.
I want to know when there is not a matching catch block for the exception generated and I don't want to display the exception generated, instead I want to display some message or want to forward to some other link or page, where should I write that message or how should I display this? Please elaborate me on this.

Comment: why the down vote? It's a legit question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is the `customErrors` property in your web.config file. It looks something like this:

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="403.htm"/>
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.htm"/>
    </customErrors>
```

This will let you redirect to your own error pages for thrown exceptions, error 403's, and error 404's.

Comment: this is the way if there any unhandeled excepttion in my code then it will forward to this page with error message ......? can i write different messages like if want in some code exception arise and no matching catch block then should show this message and for some other code if exception comes should show this message

Comment: This is a great place to start. Once you get this set up you can easily customize this view to display the exception differently depending on the logged in user or environment or whatever

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - read this article about the `customErrors` element - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet - Sure, just have your Error.aspx page display a different message for different thrown exceptions.